# Kotlin | Problem using if as expression along with also scope function

Tags: android, kotlin, lambda

I had the following code on my project:

```kotlin
val typeface = if (isBold && isItalic) {
   Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC
} else if (isBold) {
   Typeface.BOLD
} else if (isItalic) {
   Typeface.ITALIC
} else {
   Typeface.NORMAL
}

updateTypeface(typeface)
```

Then, I decided to change my code to this:

```kotlin
if (isBold && isItalic) {
   Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC
} else if (isBold) {
   Typeface.BOLD
} else if (isItalic) {
   Typeface.ITALIC
} else {
   Typeface.NORMAL
}.also { typeface ->
   updateTypeface(typeface)
}
```

But when the value of `isBold is true` and `isItalic is false`, `updateTypeface(typeface)` is not being called, although the breakpoint is stoping in the `Typeface.BOLD` line.

Am I missing something, or there's a bug here?

**Current kotlin plugin version:** 223-1.9.0-release-358-AS8836.35.2231.10811636
**Analyzer Version:** 1.9.0-release-358

**Android Studio:** Giraffe | 2022.3.1 Patch 2
**Runtime version:** 17.0.6+0-b2043.56-10027231 amd64
**VM:** OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.also { }` block is only applied to the last if else statement.
If you take this example:

```kotlin
fun test(value: Int) {
    if (value == 0) "Cond: 0"
    else if(value == 1)"Cond: 1"
    else if(value == 2) "Cond: 2"
    else if(value == 3) "Cond: 3"
    else { "Cond: 4" }.also { println(it) }
}
repeat(5) { test(it) }
```

It will print out:

```
Cond: 3
Cond: 4
```

You can test it [here](https://pl.kotl.in/hpzT2Wf0r)

To counter the issue, you can wrap all if else statements in parenthesis.

```kotlin
(
if (value == 0) "Cond: 0"
else if(value == 1)"Cond: 1"
else if(value == 2) "Cond: 2"
else if(value == 3) "Cond: 3"
else "Cond: 4"
).also { println(it) }
```

Or use a [when statement](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/control-flow.html#when-expression) without arguments.

> when can also be used as a replacement for an if-else if chain. If no
> argument is supplied, the branch conditions are simply boolean expressions, and a branch is executed when its condition is true

In your case it looks like this:

```kotlin
when {
    isBold && isItalic -> Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC
    isBold -> Typeface.BOLD
    isItalic -> Typeface.ITALIC
    else -> Typeface.NORMAL
}.also { updateTypeface(it) }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use a when construct like this:

```
val typeface = when {
    isBold && isItalic -> Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC
    isBold -> Typeface.BOLD
    isItalic -> Typeface.ITALIC
    else -> Typeface.NORMAL
}.also { updateTypeface(it) }
```